# javascript access "this" in function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, constructor

I'm trying to create a function constructor:

```
var obj = function() {
    this.num = 2;
    this.func = function() {
        // need to access the **instance** num variable here
    };
};

var instance = new obj();
```

I need to access the instance properties from a propery (which is the function func) of the object. But it doesn't work, since `this` is always the current function..

Comment: Even your code works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Store `this` in a variable which `func` can access:

```
var obj = function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.num = 2;
    _this.func = function() {
        console.log(_this.num);
    };
};
```

Comment: It's interesting that you do `_this.num` and `_this.func` too. Is that something you for consistency in your code? Because I'd just leave them as `this` and only use `_this` in the method.

Comment: @Andy That's right it's purely for consistency / maintainability. There is no performance improvement either way

Answer (score 0):

Please, use well-known approach, store `this` into separate field:

```
    var obj = function() {
      self = this;
      self.num = 2;
      self.func = function() {
       alert(self.num);
          // need to access the **instance** num variable here
      };
    };

   var instance = new obj();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern I use for the problem:

```
var obj = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.num = 2;
  this.func = function() {
    console.info(self.num);
  };
};

var instance = new obj();
```

The variable self now can be accessed in all function of obj and is always the obj itself.

This is the same then:

```
var obj = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.num = 2;
  self.func = function() {
    console.info(self.num);
  };
};

var instance = new obj();
```

Comment: I see self is a local variable. And I guess it wont be garbage collected? Does self simply created again for each scope, and it's similar to static variable in C ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the **Custom Constructor Functions**, used to create a custom constructor and it's accessed without any problem, try it:

```js
var Obj = function () {
     this.num = 2;
     this.func = function () {
         alert("I have " + this.num);
         return "I have " + this.num;
     };
};

var instance= new Obj();
instance.func();//will return and show I have 2
```